# underestimatedCount in Swift's Dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary, collections

According to the documentation, Swift's `Dictionary` type has this property named `underestimatedCount`:

> A value less than or equal to the number of elements in the
>   collection.

Anybody knows why on Westeros is this considered useful??!

Baffles me...

Comment: There's a [discussion from the mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/swift-users@swift.org/msg00614.html) and you aren't the first one to complain about [bad documentation](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-991)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Summary**: technically speaking, `underestimatedCount` belongs to `Sequence`, and gets inherited by `Collection`, and `Dictionary`. `Dictionary` doesn't override the default implementation that returns zero.

---

Looking at the source code, it seems that `underestimatedCount` is used as an indicator to determine the amount of the growth of a mutable collection when new items are added to it.

Here's a snippet from [StringCore.Swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/StringCore.swift#L688):

```
public mutating func append<S : Sequence>(contentsOf s: S)
  where S.Iterator.Element == UTF16.CodeUnit {

...........

  let growth = s.underestimatedCount
  var iter = s.makeIterator()

  if _fastPath(growth > 0) {
    let newSize = count + growth
    let destination = _growBuffer(newSize, minElementWidth: width)
```

Similarily, from [StringCharacterView.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/StringCharacterView.swift#L404):

```
public mutating func append<S : Sequence>(contentsOf newElements: S)
    where S.Iterator.Element == Character {
    reserveCapacity(_core.count + newElements.underestimatedCount)
    for c in newElements {
      self.append(c)
    }
  }
```

Or even better, from [Arrays.swift.gyb](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Arrays.swift.gyb#L1296):

```
public mutating func append<S : Sequence>(contentsOf newElements: S)
    where S.Iterator.Element == Element {
    let oldCount = self.count
    let capacity = self.capacity
    let newCount = oldCount + newElements.underestimatedCount

    if newCount > capacity {
      self.reserveCapacity(
        Swift.max(newCount, _growArrayCapacity(capacity)))
      }
    _arrayAppendSequence(&self._buffer, newElements)
  }
```

Oddly enough, I could find only one implementation for `underestimatedCount`, in [Sequence](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift#L1038), and that one returns zero.

At this time is seems that the `underestimatedCount` has more value to custom implementations of collections/sequences, as for the standard Swift collections Apple has already a good idea about the growth of those.